# POST request error: NSURLConnection HTTP load failed iOS 10

Tags: swift3, ios10, nsurlsession, app-transport-security, xcode8.2

I'm new to iOS programming. I want to connect my app to [my web service (HTTPS)](https://api.wideboard.me).

Why is XCode telling me this error when I run POST request with 'Alamofire 4.0' in iOS 10?

[image]

This error doesn't appear when I use iOS 9 simulator. I've tried various ways as people say on stackoverflow and none of them solved my problem.

**Update:**

I have added this inside my info.plist, and still get the same error.

[image]

How to implement ATS in iOS 10?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What domain?  It is a lot easier to provide suggestions if we can see what your server is actually providing.  :-)

Comment: @dgatwood, this is the domain: [link](https://api.wideboard.me)

Comment: Try running `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://api.wideboard.me/` in the terminal on your Mac. Look for errors reported.

Comment: @wottle, I did. The result is 'Pass' for all tests performed with that command line. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you updated the plist in AlamoFire, or just in your project?  You'll need to disable ATS in both.  Once you've confirmed that, update the logging as described here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/app-transport-security/ to see the exact SSL error causing your problem (if you are still seeing one after disabling ATS in the AlamoFire module.

Comment: @wottle, I have updated the info.plist in Alamofire and still get the same error. FYI, I created a completely new project in Objective-C and the http request works fine with AFNetworking. I don't know what caused it can't be executed with Alamofire and Swift.

Comment: Try changing the `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` log level up to 3 to see the exact reason for the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I changed the SSL certificate on my API domain with the trusted one as mentioned by Apple in [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207177).

Comment: I am also facing this same error, can you please explain how solved this. @user1994

Comment: This is the accurate answer. Changing app transport security doesn't do anything (I guess it is fixed in Xcode 10 onwards) and also it is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one.

If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

Please for more details refer [Apple Document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)

You need to do changes inside your Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

#### open Info.plist file like

[image: open plist]

### Add TransportSecurity inside

[image: Add inside plist]

**or**

[image: Can add also]

Comment: Actually, for clarification, forward secrecy is one of the settings you can disable in ATS that won't require additional justification upon submitting to the app store (when Apple starts to enforce that requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Mobile network, Mostly this is the reason.